# OneDrive Rest API delta token return empty data for track changes

Tags: onedrive

I use rest api

> GET https://api.onedrive.com/v1.0/drive/root/view.delta?token=*****

to get OneDrive files changes and use `@delta.token` to get next paging files(token).

My OneDrive account contain files about 100 GB(about 18000 file).

When listing changes from OneDrive it working as expected until the access token expired.

When i get new access token and continue to get changes for next request the next request provides empty value that mean there is no files remaining.

But when request again after a while with same last request (that return empty value) the response will get list files and continue as expected.

I need a solution or documentation about this issue or work around

(maybe is related to request limitation from OneDrive but there is no documentation about it).